# Integrating Facebook, but where's the best place to store variables like login status?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have integrated Facebook into my site, but where is the best place to store things like current login status? For example,

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    DS.fb.sdk.init();
    DS.fb.user.login();
}
```

gets the login status of the user, but do I save this status into cookies/databases or is there a more efficient way of saving it? If it's any help, I also want to store a lot of other things like current location etc.

Also, as a side question, are there good example links of sites that have Facebook integrated and show how they integrate Facebook and store data of the user?

Comment: The question of where to save data depends largely on what you want to do with it. Do you only need it for the current session, or do you need it long-time (database) …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are always very good to use. You can use information into session variables rather than storing them in database then extracting again from database.

Comment: I will take a look at the php api rather than the js one too